# subprocess.call without command writing to the console

Tags: python, subprocess

I am currently writing a python program that contains a section where it pings a target computer to see and it if responds, changes a variable, but when I execute the code the ping command writes to the console (which I don't want).

I have checked the ping commands parameters to see if there is something to make it silent but was unable to find anything. Is there something I can do to stop the command to echoing to the console?

My code below:

```
if platform.system().lower() == "windows":
        parameter = "-n"
    else:
        parameter = "-c"

    exitCode = subprocess.call(f"ping {parameter} 1 {activeConnections[ip][0]}")
    if (exitCode == 0):
        activeConnections[ip][3] = "T"
```

`activeConnections` is a dictionary and if the ping is successful, a value is changed from `"F"` to `"T"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`devnull`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.devnull) attribute of the built-in [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module:

```
from os import devnull
from subprocess import STDOUT

# Your code

if platform.system().lower() == "windows":
    parameter = "-n"
else:
    parameter = "-c"

with open(devnull) as DEVNULL:
    exitCode = subprocess.call(f"ping {parameter} 1 {activeConnections[ip][0]}", stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT))

if (exitCode == 0):
    activeConnections[ip][3] = "T"
```

Comment: this works but you accidentally wrote STOUT instead of STDOUT :)